# Zabbix send post data to a web monitoring task

Tags: zabbix

I have a Zabbix web monitoring task where I need to pass in JSON data to the URL via a http post. For example, the curl command to run this request is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @myData.json https://example.net
```

When I am configuring the Zabbix web monitoring task, where do I put this JSON data?

I see under the "Step of the web scenario" there are fields for 'Post', 'Variable', and 'Headers'. Does the JSON data go directly in one of those fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl --data` => it's POST request => paste your JSON data into Zabbix *Post* field + you need to set JSON header in the Zabbix *Headers* field: `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Using `{ }` as Raw data / raw post field changes my GET request into a POST request (empty body)